# Calculate stationary points in JS with math.js

Tags: javascript, equation-solving, derivative, math.js

I want to calculate the stationary points of a derivative in JavaScript with the external library [math.js](http://mathjs.org/).

So if I have `f(x) = x^2`, the derivative is `2x` and the stationary points can be calculated making `2x = 0` so `x = 0` . But the function in math.js that is `math.eval` needs to assign a value to x.

For example:

```js
let scope = {
  a: 3,
  b: 4
}
const c = math.eval('a * b', scope);
console.log(c); // 12
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs@5.0.4/dist/math.min.js"></script>
```

So how can I calculate `2x + 2 = 0` for example? I want that the result given to me is `x = -1`.

Comment: I don't think this library has solver capabilities.  I think you have to isolate terms yourself.

Comment: MathJS can only solve linear equations involving matrices.  Search [this page](http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions.html) for "solve".  It won't solve any algebraic equation.

Comment: @Amy how can I do that?